# Formula for data distribution

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, macros

I would like to know if there is a way to automatically distribute the amounts from column H into column D in 3 sections (Blue, Green, and Yellow) starting from D28 (Start) and climbing to the top D3 (End) filling them in that order from bottom to top, without exceeding the quantity circled in red for each group (Less Than or Equal to), can't use amounts from column H twice.

For example:

The formula distributes H6, H7, and H15 into Column D starting (Start) from D28 to D26 (Yellow Group), the sum of these quantities (sum=2287) is close to 2300 "less or equal to" (Amount circled in red), then it will proceed to do the same with the green group and leave the blue group to the end.

Example Picture:

[image: Example Picture]

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: Did you try to use the Excel Solver?

Comment: I will try, thank you very much, Carl. I am seriously breaking my head right now to solve this.

Comment: Is it correct that that you have in H less rows than the cells you want to fill? Should the end then only be zeros?

Comment: That is correct. I want excel to distribute column H (Weights, Boxes) into Column D (Truck Container, which can fit 25 boxes). D is the truck container we want to fill with Column H (Weight, 18 boxes) the truck container is divided into 3 parts which can only hold a certain weight per axis. We always fill the truck from bottom to top.

Comment: I assume that also means that the yellow part should have ideally gave 3 boxes, the green one 10 and the rest is distributed to the Blue. Or does this not matter as long as it is within thresholds

Comment: That is correct. For example: If we have 22 boxes, the first 3 boxes will go to the yellow part, 10 boxes to the green part, and the remaining 9 boxes to the blue part, in that order. the reason is, that we always fill the yellow part first, the yellow part represents the end of the container, green represents the middle part of the container, and the blue part is the very front. I am doing it manually right now. I will edit the post to add the picture for reference. The end of the container starts from numbers 1 to 3, the middle of the container is 4 to 13 and the front part is 14 to 22.

Comment: @CharlesArreola It seems to me that if you turned the image of the truck upside down, cockpit up, then the task would become a little easier - the need to move from the bottom up introduces additional difficulties. Can you please tell me if the boxes inside eje should be sorted by weight? Well, these three boxes in the first section - where to put the heaviest one, closer to the cab or closer to section 2?

Comment: Hi, you are right, that will help definitely, I will change the order. We always load the heaviest boxes in Axis 2 or 3 which is represented in the first image as the color green (can only load 8368 Kg) and color blue (can only load 8832 Kg) as per the yellow Axis, it can only load (2300 Kg). The "Eje" column is where I manually input the weight of the boxes to then proceed to copy/paste them to the "Gross Weight G.W" Column highlighted with light red, once it is there it will automatically reflect to the truck (Green boxes with numbers which represent the boxes in the "Docks" area).

Comment: @CharlesArreola Yes, the weight distribution by zones: the specified number of places (boxes, pallets) should be placed in such a way that the weight of the first two zones is maximum, but does not exceed the specified limits - 2300 and 8368. The closer will be to the specified values, the more cargo can be transported at a time. Do you need to somehow balance the weight within each zone? For example, keep the left and right weights approximately equal, or it is desirable to move heavier units forward or backward along the platform (the stability of the truck on the track depends on this?)